# Simple Desktop GUI Architecture

Tags: user-interface, architecture

Previously while designing desktop applications, I have always found it hard to architecture a clean way for different windows to communicate with each other.

For example: A settings/option dialog window that modifies the behavior of the main window.

Would making my "Main" (e.g. where there should only ever be one instance of a window visible at a time) Singletons be a good idea? Since there are only supposed to be one at a time anyways?

This would make it easier, and cleaner for separate windows to communicate.

If the above is true, then I could add Facade-like methods for a clean interface to other windows.

For example:
MainWindow.setFont(Font f);

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Does either window know about the other? ie. is code in the main window responsible for showing the setting window, as an example?

Comment: Did you consider using an Application object as the singleton to help windows communicate?

Comment: @9000. Yes I have. But this seemed a bit tidier, and extendable.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen. I Guess in my simple example it does. There I could just use a inner-class. But I had in mind larger applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good read on the topic is [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) from Martin Fowler which covers various design patterns. For example the [Observer Synchronization](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/MediatedSynchronization.html) pattern might work for you in the context of the referenced article.

If you can, I suggest that you stick to some well known framework since writing your own can be a daunting task.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm not trying to engineer an entire framework, just a good way to organize my GUI...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of things that Qt gets right. If you want to communicate to a window send it a signal - then the window can deal with receiving the signal or not, the sender doesn't need to care if it even exists.

Comment: Answering OpenCV questions are frustrating aint it? Rarely ppl upvote and almost never the OP comes back to accept the answer.

Comment: @karlphillip - the problem is also that openCV 'official' list is a terrible yahoo groups site - there is nowhere for advanced opencv users either